# Height of parent elements increase if content is truncated

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I really can't reproduce my problem, so I just post a link to my current website where the problem is occurring:  [here](http://felivere.de/test/onepager#event_1).

I am trying to truncate the content of the `.event-description`-div if its content is greater than the div. Therefore the `.event-description`-class is defined as follows:

```
.event-description {
    height: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But if the content is greater than the initial width and height (which is based on the resolution of the browser), the content indeed is truncated, but all the other parent divs increase their size in height as well. I am using bootstrap 3 as well as some jquery libraries, so maybe the problem is originating from there.

Edit: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHj00.jpg) screenshot shows the default and wanted behavior if the content of the right div is not overflowing. 
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3siRD.jpg) screenshot shows the unwanted behavior. The content is indeed truncated, but for some odd reason all other elements increased their height, which should not happen.

Comment: Can you show us a bit of your Html code ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.col-md-4` to

```
.col-md-4 {
    max-height: 70%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

And remove the rules you inserted yourself, i.e. these ones:

```
.event-description {
    height: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It might be better to apply the rules I added to the `event-wrapper` class though, because you might not want to interfer with the default CSS of your framework.

Comment: Thanks for the fast respond. Unfortunately this does not seem to work. The content is truncated but the other elements still get bigger.

Comment: @tastyPI Not when I tested it. Make sure to remove height 100% from .col-md-4 and from event-wrapper.

Comment: That's odd. I changed .col-md-4 accordingly to you. I also removed all attributes from the .event-description class as well as the height attribute from .event-wrapper. But still: the picture on the left side is getting bigger.

Comment: @tastyPI Unless you can make a small as possible test case, I cannot help you. Your website is a pain in the *ss to test because the sections snap to the browsers height, you have some annoying JS plugins running, so I can't reasonably test everything. Also, it isn't clear to me what exactly you want, so a mock-up would be nice as well. Please improve your original answer and then get back to me.

Comment: As I said I can't really reproduce it...but I update the website. I removed the footer and the auto-scrolling. I also added some screenshots.

Comment: @tastyPI Thanks for the edit. The website still auto scrolls/snaps to sections though. Could you disable that behaviour for now; for testing?

Comment: I just removed that behavior as well. Thank you for still working on my problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96480/discussion-between-bram-vanroy-and-tastypi).